# Magento hosting requirements for small website, max 500 vistors/day

Tags: upgrade, hosting

I am going to upgrade the cloud VPS of my company.
Here the current configuration:

- 2 cores, 2GB RAM, 20GB SSD storage
- Apache with Nginx for serving static contents
- Magento 1.8.1 with around 400 products (not SKUs). Currently we setup the website just only for viewing product information. We will set up for placing order online 1 year in the future.
- No Varnish, No Redis, No Full-page-cache or any kinds of cacheing, just Magento's default caching.

Currently, max is 500 visitors and 2000 page views per day but only when we run marketing campaigns, normally just around 300-350 visitors per day. We are growing but not so fast.

BUt the speed of the website is not fast enough. So I will install Varnish, Redis and Full-page-cache in order to make it faster. I am going to upgrade the VPS to 4 cores and 4GB RAM.

I want to ask you guys whether new configuration is sufficient or I have to go for more CPU and RAM.

Comment: good enough, just limit memory for varnish and redis, so they wont eat it all.

Comment: would you consider adding the magento version?

Comment: @user5198077: It will be Magento 1.9.x. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of traffic a 4CPU/4GB RAM machine will be adequate, I do have some recommendations though:

- Redis for caching/session management is what I would recommend but MySQL is good enough for handling sessions.
- I would only tend to use Varnish on high traffic websites, it is a full page caching tool but it can be inefficient if you don't get a high amount of traffic so that Varnish has enough of those pages in cache when they get visited. For the amount of traffic you're doing I wouldn't invest the time to set it up for now.
- Installing Aoe_ClassPathCache as an alternative to the compiler is something I often recommend doing - https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_ClassPathCache
- Ensure your PHP config isn't setup to eat all of the memory, your webserver/Redis won't use up much

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already subcribed a VPS of 3 core CPU and 6BG of RAM. I setup Zend Opcache, https and HTTP/2. I installed Varnish and Redis but have not configured. I think I will config Varnish after upgrading to Magento 2.